# IOS WKWebView - Hide website Header & Footer

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, xcode10, swift4.1

How can i hide header and footer through loading url using **Wkwebview** ? Most probably to pass some param or cookies that webpage read and take action against.

```
class TermCond_PrivacyPoli_VC: UIViewController , WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate {



var HC = "https://www.hospi24.com/hospi24/company/privacy";


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let  webViewK = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 70, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height))
    self.view.addSubview(webViewK)
    webViewK.uiDelegate = self;
    webViewK.navigationDelegate = self
    let url = URL.init(string: "https://www.hospi24.com/hospi24/company/privacy") //URL (string: TNC)
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    webViewK.load(request)

}



func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print("finish to load")
}


func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {

    print("finish to load")
    let elementID = "bottomMenu"
    let removeElementIdScript = "var element = document.getElementsByClassName(('\(elementID)[0].style.display=\"none\";'); element.parentElement.removeChild(element);"
    webView.evaluateJavaScript(removeElementIdScript) { (response, error) in
        debugPrint("Am here")
    }
}
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: i want to hide Header & Footer from website URL after load url into WKWebview

Comment: You can hide header and footer by passing cookie param in your request. So in server side on the base of cookie Header and footer will be visible, or you can apply Javascript code to make it disable after loading the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide header and footer by passing cookie param in your request. So in server side on the base of cookie Header and footer will be visible, or you can apply Javascript code to make it disable through JavaScript, you can use this code in **didFinish** Delegate

```
public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
 self.wkwebView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById(\"header\").style.display='none';") { (result, error) in
        if error == nil {
            // header is hide now
        }
}
```